Given a binary string, count number of dense sub-strings in O(nlogn) time
Dense sub-string: number of 1's > number of 0's
Brute force approach in C++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int bin_dense_count_bruteforce(string s) {
    int n = s.size();
    int ans = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<=n-1; i++) {
        int statusNow = 0;
        
        for(int j=i; j<=n-1; j++) {
            if(s[j] == '1')
                statusNow++;
            else
                statusNow--;

            if(statusNow>0)
                ans++;
        }
    }

    return ans;
}

int main() {
    string s = "11000101";

    cout<<bin_dense_count_bruteforce(s)<<endl;
    // 7
    // i, j substring
    // 0, 0 1
    // 0, 1 11
    // 0, 2 110
    // 1, 1 1
    // 5, 5 1
    // 5, 7 101
    // 7, 7 1

    return 0;
}

I tried thinking about any approach with unordered_map, like prefix sum like approach or similar way. I have tried searching online and even chatgpt, claude, etc. but no success.

You can achieve the result in O(n), why do you want it in O(nlogn)?

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-of-substrings-in-a-binary-string-that-contains-more-1s-than-0s/

@LisanAlGaib Any algorithm that is O(n) is also O(nlogn), so what are you really asking? If you have such a solution, feel free to post an answer.

Exactly,  that is why I'm asking why specifically o(nlogn) is the requirement mentioned in the question. O(n) answer is already suggested by LMeyer.

@LisanAlGaib The answer by L. Meyer is Θ(nlogn) as binary indexed trees take logarithmic time for updates and queries.

First, a quick search on Google will give you this useful page https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-of-substrings-in-a-binary-string-that-contains-more-1s-than-0s/
If we take the prefix sum pre, the array counting the difference between ones and zeros:
pre[i+1] = count of 1s in s[0..i] - number of 0s in s[0..i]

The problem is equivalent to:
find all (i, j) with i < j such as pre[i] < pre[j].

Where i, j can go from 0 to n. Hence, it's similar to counting the inversion. A fenwick tree is able to do it in O(nlog(n)) but it's not the only solution.
To prevent indexes to be negative, they can be shift by n.
vector<int> p(n+1);
FenwickTree<long long> ft(2*n+1);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  p[i+1] += (s[i] == '1'?1:-1)+p[i];
  ft.update(n+p[i+1], +1);
}
long long ans = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
  ans += ft.query_greater_than(n+p[i-1]);
  if (i != 1) ft.update(n+p[i-1],-1);
}

The result might not fit a int as it could be equivalent to n^2.
